# Update content of static html file in Django

Tags: python, django, service-worker, django-staticfiles, pythonanywhere

I saved an HTML as a static file in order to save it in cache and render it through a service worker when Offline. I would like to make a small change on my HTML in order to get the appropriate encoding. I am using pythonanywhere as my server. And I have defined in my settings.py the following paths:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = u'/home/cocoa/cocoa/static'
```

When I look at my file in the server in the following directory is:

/home/cocoa/cocoa/static/login/Offline/HTML/mEstado.html

My file looks like this:

If I visit the following URL:

https://cocoa.pythonanywhere.com/static/login/Offline/HTML/mEstado.html

My file looks like this:

I allready tried reloading on shift. Unabling the service-worker and

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

But nothing seems to work. I do not know where the problem is, nor how to solve it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like there were some images you meant to put in the post...?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to clear you browser cache? `Ctrl+F5`. I think problem in cached html file because you run it from static. As I know browser caches all static files from django static folder.